# ¿Un sistema que saque el promedio de x numero de notas, con interfaz gráfica?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

```
if listbox.size() <= 1:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Tienes que tener mas de una nota para poder sacar el promedio", title="Error_notas")
    else:
        suma = 0
        for elemento in listbox:
            suma = suma + elemento
            print("El promedio es: {}".format(suma))
```

Quiero hacer un sistema que saque una cierta cantidad de notas para esto usé ````Listbox`de`tkinter```, pues me parecía una buena opción y cree una variable que guardara todo lo que ponga en la entrada, usé lo siguiente `tk.DoubleVar()` y de ese modo pude poner numeros decimales.

El problema radica en que quiero que todos los elementos que están en `listbox` se sumen entre si, y quise que se imprimiera la suma en la terminal para comprobar que todo funcionara, pero me sale el siguiente error "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str" y como vieron, intenté imprimir esta suma usandon el método `format` pero aun así, sigue dandome ese error.

Les pido que me ayuden para imprimir esta suma en la terminal, y si ven que algo se puede mejorar en el código acepto cualquier sugerencial. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Miguel

Te recomiendo usar Numpy, es una librería muy buena para realizar este tipo de fórmulas estadísticas.

Una vez que la instales con el comando "pip install numpy", solo la importas y llamas la función numpy.mean. La función trabaja en base a una lista, así que estarás bien con lo que ya llevas creo.

Citando la documentación:

La función numpy.mean devuelve el promedio de los elementos del array a. Por defecto se calcula el promedio del array una vez aplanado. Si se indica un eje, solo se considerará dicho eje en el cálculo.

Por cierto, el error de concatenación te está saliendo porque la variable "suma" es un int aparentemente. Trata de convertirlo a string con suma = str(suma)

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda, tomare todo en cuenta se los agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que para obtener los valores del `Listbox` utilices `elementos=listbox.get(0,listbox.size())`, si los elementos no son `float`, entonces tendrás que convertirlos con `float(elemento)` dentro de tu `for`. Un ejemplo podría ser:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

tk = Tk()

listbox=Listbox(tk)
listbox.pack()

def agregarNota():
    try:
        nota=float(entry.get())
        listbox.insert(listbox.size()-1,nota)
        entry.delete(0,END)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror(message="Debe ingresar una nota válida", title="Error_notas")

def calcularPromedio():
    if listbox.size() <= 1:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Tienes que tener más de una nota para poder sacar el promedio", title="Error_notas")
    else:
        suma = 0

        elementos=listbox.get(0,listbox.size())
        length=len(elementos)

        promedio=sum(elementos)/length if length>0 else 0
        mensaje="El promedio es: {}".format(round(promedio,3))

        # for elemento in elementos:
        #     suma = suma + elemento
        print(mensaje)
        messagebox.showinfo(message=mensaje, title="Promedio")

entry=Entry(tk)
entry.pack()
button_agregar=Button(tk, text="Nueva nota", fg="white", bg="black", command=agregarNota)
button_agregar.pack()

button=Button(tk, text="Calcular", fg="white", bg="black", command=calcularPromedio)
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

En este caso se ingresan los valores al `Listbox` como `float`, por tanto, `elementos` contendrá una lista con todas las notas, permitiendo utilizar la función `sum` que devuelve la suma de dichas notas. Para calcular el promedio sólo tienes que dividir el resultado de la suma entre la cantidad de elementos de la lista, validando que si no hay elementos, entonces el promedio es 0.

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de seguir todas las recomendaciones y el programa funciona a la perfeccion gracias por la valiosa informacion.